# Как сканировать все ip для TCP/ip подключения

Tags: c++, udp, tcp-ip

Пытаюсь сделать некое подобие чата на Winsock, и там нужно чтобы клиент и сервер знали ip и порт друг друга. Как сделать так, что бы сервер просматривал все ip для подключения клиента к нему. Мне кажется, что проще всего будет отправить ip клиента серверу через UDP, и после подключаться через TCP, если я правильно понял суть TCP и UDP. Если нужно использовать UDP, то какой библиотекой пользоваться?

Comment: если сервер и клиент находятся в одной локальной сети - вас спасет широковещательный UDP, если сервер и клиент в разных подсетях и у вас нет доступа к настройке самих подсетей - вам UDP не поможет ничем, широковещательные пакеты по умолчанию ходят только в своей подсети и не покидают ее границ... есть еще всякие мультикасты, но рано если возникает подобный вопрос...

Comment: Что-то я не очень понял задачу и проблему, зачем серверу знать ip клиента?

Comment: @andreymal в Winsock для создания сокета TCP/ip нужно знать ip и порт. Я например хотел бы подключиться к другу, зная его ip, а он не знает мой, то как я понимаю, мы не сможем подключиться для передачи данных. Могу скинуть код до которого я пока дошёл)

Comment: @Cucimber клиент должен знать ip сервера для подключения к нему, а вот серверу знать ip клиента совершенно необязательно (система автоматически его узнает, когда клиент попытается подключиться)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо